# Java method returns double | int

Tags: java, int, double, primitive

I need a method that will accept String number as a parameter and return double if it has a remainder, or int if it is decimal.

I wrote such code:

```
 private double convertToNumber(String number) {
    double d = Double.parseDouble(number);
    if (d % 1.0 == 0) {
        return Integer.parseInt(number);
    } else {
        return d;
    }
}
```

but as signature of this method is double it returns double in any case.

Please give me some hint.

Comment: How would you call this function?

Comment: private double currentTotal;
public void divide(String number) {
        currentTotal /= convertToNumber(number);
}

Comment: This is just one example, I will use it in some other operations as well. The problem that I need an int if this digit is whole number, without a dot.

Comment: @DimaSan How would the other operations call it?

Comment: the same way, please look [link](https://gist.github.com/DimaSanKiev/ab44c90293756069ab92)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quire sure I understand the intention of returning a `double` or and `int` knowing that's not really possible for a single function to return different data types.

What I think I understand from your sample code, is that if a String (For example, "123.0" doesn't matter how many trailing zeros) is passed into the `CalculatorEngine`, from the [link](https://gist.github.com/DimaSanKiev/ab44c90293756069ab92) you provided, you want it to be treated as an `int` and for the math operator to perform calculations with an `int` and a `double` (since currentTotal is a `double`).

Now after all the calculations are done, if currentTotal ends with a .0 then you probably want that treated as an int also and drop the point, otherwise keep the point.

If I'm understanding this correctly, here's what I think `CalculatorEngine` might look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CalculatorEngine ce = new CalculatorEngine();
    ce.equal("1.01");
    ce.add("12");
    System.out.println(ce.getTotalString());
    ce.subtract("0.01");
    System.out.println(ce.getTotalString());
    ce.multiply("100.00000");
    System.out.println(ce.getTotalString());
    ce.divide("123");
    System.out.println(ce.getTotalString());
}

public static class CalculatorEngine {
    private enum Operator {
        ADD, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY, DIVIDE
    }

    private double currentTotal;

    public CalculatorEngine() {
        currentTotal = 0;
    }

    public String getTotalString() {
        return currentTotal % 1.0 == 0 
                ? Integer.toString((int)currentTotal) 
                : String.valueOf(currentTotal);
    }

    public void equal(String number) {
        currentTotal = Double.parseDouble(number);
    }

    public void add(String number) {
        convertToDouble(number, Operator.ADD);
    }

    public void subtract(String number) {
        convertToDouble(number, Operator.SUBTRACT);
    }

    public void multiply(String number) {
        convertToDouble(number, Operator.MULTIPLY);
    }

    public void divide(String number) {
        convertToDouble(number, Operator.DIVIDE);
    }

    public void changeSign(String number) {
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(number);
        currentTotal = d * (-1);
    }

    public void dot(String number) {
        // todo
    }

    private boolean isDouble(String number) {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(number);
        return d % 1.0 != 0;
    }

    private void convertToDouble(String number, Operator operator) {
        double dblNumber = Double.parseDouble(number);
        switch (operator) {
            case ADD:
                add(dblNumber);
                break;
            case SUBTRACT:
                subtract(dblNumber);
                break;
            case MULTIPLY:
                multiply(dblNumber);
                break;
            case DIVIDE:
                divide(dblNumber);
                break;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError(operator.name());   
        }
    }

    private void add(double number) {
        currentTotal += number % 1.0 == 0 ? (int)number : number;
    }

    private void subtract(double number) {
        currentTotal -= number % 1.0 == 0 ? (int)number : number;
    }

    private void multiply(double number) {
        currentTotal *= number % 1.0 == 0 ? (int)number : number;
    }

    private void divide(double number) {
        currentTotal /= number % 1.0 == 0 ? (int)number : number;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
13.01
13
1300
10.56910569105691
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything works exactly as I expected!I like your idea of using `enum` here. I really appreciate your advice. Pity that I still can't vote.

Comment: @DimaSan You're welcome.  If you found this answer useful, kindly click the check mark so your question is solved and consider up voting it :-)

Comment: It's perfectly possible for a method to return different types -- as long as a common super type (`class` or `interface`) exists for the types.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of your function can only be of one (1) type, either int or double, but not both. You can maybe try to redesign your function to return a boolean if the number has a fractional part (true) or (false) it doesn't.

Please remember that integers can't hold fractional parts, so operations like

```
int a = 3 / 2;
```

will set `a`to `1` not to `1.5`

Answer (score 3):

Why not return a [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) from your method:

```
private Number convertToNumber(String number) {
    double d = Double.parseDouble(number);
    if (d % 1.0 == 0) {
        return Integer.parseInt(number);
    } else {
        return d;
    }
}
```

Both `Integer` and `Double` are subclasses of `Number`.

Comment: Because Number is an abstract class

Comment: And how is that a problem?

Comment: He'll have the exact same problem as before. Does he have an int or a double after the function returns? Neither, he has a Number.

Comment: I understood he's problem was with the implicit type-cast to `double` even when the method returned an `int` (because the signature had `double` as return type). Using a `Number` as return value you can do an `instanceof` check in client code to distinguish between `Integer`s and `Double`s.

Comment: Which means a lot of instanceof checks in his code if he has to call this function over and over. The point of writing this function is likely to conform to the DRY principle. if he has to do instanceof checks he may as well get rid of this function and do the parsing without calling the function.

Comment: Yes it may works but in that case I'll need to do instanceOf check every time.

Comment: If you would need many `instanceof` checks, then to me that means you should parse the `String` value into an `int` or `double` somewhere higher up in your call hierarchy. It's difficult to give a better suggestion unless you post more code. I just wanted to point out that it _is possible_ to return an `Integer` or a `Double` from the same method by using plain old subtyping (something that's claimed to be impossible in some of the other answers).

Comment: Thanks for help Mick, here is my full code [link](https://gist.github.com/DimaSanKiev/ab44c90293756069ab92). I need to decide, maybe i need to add another variable like private int currentTotalInt and store there an int value or to use Number convertToNumber() method that you advice me.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the link for others to see as well? At a quick glance, I don't understand why you would need to distinguish between `double` and `int`, because the calculator's `currentTotal` variable is a `double`. As a side note, you might be better off using a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) in your calculations. If you're looking for ways to _display_ the results, [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) might prove useful.

Comment: Yes, you're right I think first of all I have to redesign my class, because now it works right (it stores `double` values into `double` variable). And then to change  `double` to `BigDecimal` variable. Thank you a lot for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two different return types or change the method's return type in Java. You can have different method signatures with different return types but then you're calling two separate methods which defeats the purpose of what you are trying to accomplish.

The best you can do in your case is create an object that you pass into the function in which you will set a flag that tells you which value to read. You will also populate either the int value or the double value.

When the method returns the boolean flag will tell the client code which value is the correct one to consume.

```
class MyConverter {
    public String number;
    public boolean isInt;
    public double doubleVal;
    public int intVal;
}

 private void convertToNumber(MyConverter conv) {
    double d = Double.parseDouble(conv.number);
    if (d % 1.0 == 0) {
        conv.isInt = true;
        conv.intVal = Integer.parseInt(number);
    } else {
        conv.doubleVal = d;
    }
}
```

Comment: private void convertToNumber couldn't return neither int nor double.

Comment: @DimaSan - Oops, sorry. Was rushing. There should be no return value. Just assignments to variables. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is to create a base class and two classes which extends first class.

IntegerClass has an integer attribute and FloatClass a float atrribute. Then inside the method you instsntiate IntegerClass or FloatClass depending of the String, but you returns the BaseClass.

Then using instanceOf determine which is returned.